# pollInterval in replicationhandler of SOLR

Tags: solr

Right now it looks like pollinterval in replicationhandler is really just an interval? I have two slaves replicating from a single build master. Since those two are replicating at the same time, network bandwidth usage is too high. Is there a way to interleave two replications but still using the same pollinterval? Ideally replicationhandler needs to support cronjob like scheduling parameters?

Comment: If we do not do two replications concurrently, your search results will be inconsistent. The First slave will return results containing new documents replicated from the master and the Second slave may not have those documents, as replication is yet to happen for it..

Comment: Yeah, that is one concern I have. But I am hoping to have them off by a couple of minutes so hopefully not a big issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the interleave cannot be done by configurations. One option is to turn one of the salve as repeater, that will make the replication sequence as master->**[repeater](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#Setting_up_a_Repeater)**->slave. and only one replication will happening at a time.

The other option is to disable the replication by default, and use [**Solr HTTP API**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#HTTP_API) to trigger the replication on your end.

Comment: For my situation, using solr HTTP API to trigger seems to be a better way to go for. thanks!